# applying ROUND to 2 columns added together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the statement below, is there a way to round the final calculation to 4 decimal places?  I can only figure out how to apply ROUND to the columns individually.
The columns are both FLOAT.

```
SELECT (ISNULL([COLUMN A],0) + ISNULL([Column B],0)) AS TOTAL
```

Comment: ROUND(ISNULL([COLUMN A],0) + ISNULL([Column B],0), 4) AS TOTAL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
SELECT ROUND((ISNULL([COLUMN A],0) + ISNULL([Column B],0)), 4) AS TOTAL
```

**edit** @jarlh was slightly faster...

Comment: I was missing one of my left parenthesis.  Sigh...I'm a moron.  Thank you.

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us :P

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using `ROUND()` as jarlh mentioned above or alternatively, using `CAST()` if you want to remove the trailing 0's.

```
SELECT CAST((ISNULL([COLUMN A],0) + ISNULL([COLUMN B],0)) AS NUMERIC(38,4)) AS TOTAL
```

For example:

```
SELECT ROUND((ISNULL(5.66666,0) + ISNULL(7.22222222,0)) , 4) AS TOTAL -- 12.88890000
SELECT CAST((ISNULL(5.66666,0) + ISNULL(7.22222222,0)) AS NUMERIC(38,4)) AS TOTAL -- 12.8889
```